# how to update database with data collected using a Wizard web control?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I've tried a demo on how to use the ASP.NET Wizard web Control.

Now after collecting data in each step, how do I save the data to the database? I just do not see how. Actually, I didn't find any example telling me how to do so. I don't even know if I have to use a data-source control or just hook-up the wizard to the database.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wizard Control is just like any other Page, Except it hides & Displays controls in the Current Step.

You could go about your problem in 2 ways:

1) After User moves to new Step, by clicking NEXT, capture all fields data in the current step, and store it in the Database.

2) If you want the user to complete the whole wizard before saving data to the Database, Handle the Finish Button Click, and retreve all controls value, and store them in Database.

You can get Control values pretty straightforwardly: ControlName.Proprty (Text/SelectedIndex/Checked, etc).

does this help?